# How do I check to see if any of the words in a list are in each row within a column

Tags: python, excel, csv

Right now I currently have a list of the most common words in column1: list1, that I've extracted from a csv file.
How do I check each cell in column 2 to see if that cell contains any of the words in list1, and if so label it a 1 if it does have any of the words or 0 if it doesn't.

Comment: Please add an example further clarifying your question

Comment: ex/ list1 contains the 3 most common words from every cell combined in column 1. list1=[test, need, class]. How do I check if any of these 3 words are in each cell within column 2. For example if row 1 in column 2 said "We need milk to study for our test" it would return a 1 because that cell has the word "need" and "test" in it which are in list1. And if there weren't any words in that cell it would've returned a 0 instead

Comment: As @Akanksha said, please always include an [mcve] in your question. It's important for folks to be able to clearly see what you've tried, and what your input data is. Without clearly seeing your input data, it's difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you looking for but...

```
def column_check(list1,list2):
    for word in list2:
        if word in list1:
            return 1
    return 0

print(column_check(list1, list2)
```